# Is dropped data can still be seen in pandas?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I'm a beginner in Python and the Pandas library, and I'm rather confused by some basic functionality of DataFrame. I was dropping my data frame and has stated inplace=True so my data should be dropped. But why am I still seeing my data when I show it using head or iloc function? I've checked my data using .info() and notice that the data is dropped already by the difference of the data count before stating inplace=True.

So why can I still see my dropped data? Any explanation or pointer would be great. Thanks

[Pict](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXx0H.png)

Comment: I don't know how that happened but if you want to drop rows that have NaN value you should use `df.dropna(inplace=True)` instead of applying `.dropna` to a column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have `NaN` in olny one column, just use `df.dropna(inplace=True)`
This should get you the result you want.

The reason why your code is not working is because when you do `df['to_address']` , you are working with only that column & the output is as series (using `inplace=True` will not have an effect) which the contents of the column with the `NaN` rows removed.

You can use `df = df.dropna(subset=['to_address'])` as well.